# foreach and GetEnumerator / asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, foreach

Hi I've got problem with foreach statement. I have my controller method:

```
public ActionResult ShowComments(int id)
{
    EntryBox entrybox = new EntryBox();
    entrybox.entry = (from e in BlogDB.Enteries
                      where e.id == id
                      select e) as Entry;
    entrybox.comments = (from c in BlogDB.Comments
                         where c.EntryID == id
                         select c) as List<Comment>;
    Captcha captcha = new Captcha();

    ViewData.Model = entrybox;

    return View(); 
}
```

my viewModel:

```
public class EntryBox
{
    public Entry entry;
    public List<Comment> comments;
}
```

and when I want to display list of my comments I'm not able to because of this error:

> Error 2 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'void' because 'void' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
>   c:...\Views\Home\ShowComments.aspx

My 3 first line of View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<BlogMaker_v06.viewModels.EntryBox>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="BlogMaker_v06.Models" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentHolder" runat="server">
<% User LoggedAs = HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedAs"] as User; %>

   <div style="width: 90%">
     <b>Treść komentowanego wpisu: <br /><br /></b>
       <p style="text-indent: 10px; text-align: justify;">
           <%= Model.entry.EntryContent.TagsParse()  %>
      </p>   
              <% Html.BeginForm("AddComment/" + ViewData["id"].ToString(), "Home");
        {     %>
        Write your comment: <br />
        <table>
        <tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="Author" id="Author" value="<%= LoggedAs.Login %>" onfocus="javascript:this.value='';" <% if (LoggedAs.id != 2) {%> disabled <%}%>/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Website:</td><td><input type="text" name="AuthorWebsite" id="AuthorWebsite" value="http://" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Przepisz cyframi: <%= ViewData["captcha"] %></td><td><input type="text" name="Captcha" id="Captcha" /></td></tr>
        </table>
        <textarea name="CommentContent" id="CommentContent" rows="5" cols="25" style="width: 100%; height: 10%; border: 1px solid #C0C0C0"></textarea><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Add comment" /> 
     <% }     %>

      <br /><br />
      <b>Komentarze użytkowników:</b> 
  <% foreach (var comment in ViewData.Model.comments.Reverse())
   {

       Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/CommentTemplate.ascx", comment);    

 } %>
 </div>
```

I know it isnt good way to displaying data but I'm about refactory my whole project. 
foreach displaying commentTemplate.ascx causes problem. Captcha is my simple way to authorize human being. and I'm sure it works well.

Comment: off topic, but what is your `captcha` doing? It's not being passed to the View.

Comment: Can you post rest of view? are you looping through comments only ?

Comment: forgot to ask... where is the foreach?

Comment: also, the `entrybox.comments =` portion of your code shouldn't be necessary if you create the DB relationship in your DBML file.  IE: it will already be populated from your first `select` if your DB relationship is correct.

Comment: yup It's true - but I'm still learning (as you can see my code, I'm total beginner) - The next step of my education it will be database optimization :)

Comment: the reason I asked about the Captcha is because you don't appear to be sending the Captcha object from your ActionResult to your View.  Your view is looking for ViewData["Captcha"] but you don't create that in your ActionResult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit after seeing your foreach loop.*

`Reverse()` returns a void - it alters the list by reversing it, and does not return the list.  You are trying to "foreach" over the return value of `Reverse()`, which is void - hence the error.

You can either remove your call to `Reverse()` (and populate it in reverse order), or add something like this to the controller:

```
entrybox.comments.Reverse();
```

Or put it in your view if you must:

```
<% ViewData.Model.comments.Reverse();
   foreach (var comment in ViewData.Model.comments)
   {

       Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/CommentTemplate.ascx", comment);    

 } %>
```

Comment: will LINQ not already populate the `entrybox.comments` as a `List(Of Comments)` if the appropriate relationship is build in the designer?